# Prevent js-beautify from adding extra whitespace / empty lines

Tags: sass, whitespace, js-beautify

js-beautify (used under VSCode) annoys me by putting extra lines after comments:

My sample.scss

```
/* a fancy comment */
.foo-bars {
    background: $gray;
    display: block;

    width: 26px !important;
}
```

...becomes...

```
/* a fancy comment */
                      <-- annoying empty line inserted
.foo-bars {
    background: $gray;
    display: block;
                     <--- (this is fine. I like it being preserved)
    width: 26px !important;
}
```

This is my `.jsbeautifyrc` (verified to be effective, i.e. by testing with `"indent_char": "#"`)

```
{
    "indent_char": " ",
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 8,
    "keep-array-indentation": true,
    "break_chained_methods": false,
    "newline_between_rules": false,
    "selector_separator_newline": false,
    "end_with_newline": false
}
```

*update*: Affects `/* block comments */` only, not `// line comments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that this should have been fixed ([js-beautify#609](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/609)) but somehow didn’t work out as expected as there is still an open [issue#531](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/531) and a pending [pull request](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/pull/1145) regarding this problem.

As you mentioned you could use `// line comments` as a workaround for now.

Comment: The use of `//` for commenting in CSS is non-standard, will cause problems and is discouraged